# Trouble bringin window to focus in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble bringing a window to focus. All examples show using FindWindow function and calling SetForegroundWindow, but this did not work.
Here is what that code looked like

```
thandle = FindWindow(Nothing, "title of window")
SetForegroundWindow(thandle)
```

I then tried the ShowWindow functions. The below code worked if the window was minimized, and if the window wasn't maximized but it refused to bring focus to the window if it was already maximized.

```
If IsIconic(thandle) Then
   ShowWindow(thandle, 9)
Else
   ShowWindow(thandle, 3)
```

So then I came up with the work around that if the window isn't minimized, minimize it and then maximize it.

```
If IsIconic(thandle) Then
   ShowWindow(thandle, 9)
Else
   ShowWindow(thandle, 7)
   ShowWindow(thandle, 9)
End If
```

I would really like to know why SetForegroundWindow does not bring the window to the foreground

Comment: The [documentation for SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) explains very clearly what criteria must be met in order for the function to succeed. Clearly you've not met that criteria. (Why would you post here without at least reading the official documentation for the function first?)

Comment: I did read the documentation and my assumption was that I met this condition "The process was started by the foreground process." If my application doesn't find "title of window", it will open it. Since it was that application that opened it, I assumed it was also the foreground process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Long
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "USER32.DLL" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim thandle = FindWindow(Nothing, "Calculator")
    SetForegroundWindow(thandle)
End Sub
```